# Install app from Eclipse to /system/app at compile time

Tags: android, eclipse, root

I'm installing my application in /system/app folder. But it very difficult every time use ADB for do it. Is there any way to install app at compile time from Eclipse to /system/app folder?

This commands I'm using for install. But I want avtomate this commands from Eclipse when I press Run button. How can I do it?

```
adb push C:\XXX.apk /sdcard/XXX.apk
adb shell
su
mount -t rfs -o remount,rw /dev/block/stl9 /system
busybox cp /sdcard/XXX.apk /system/app/XXX.apk
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

For development work, you can run "adb install" from a command line, or let Eclipse run the "adb install" for you automagically.

If you want to "publish" your .apk, you'd typically use Android Market.

Here are a few options that don't necessarily require Android Market:

http://maketecheasier.com/install-applications-without-the-market/2011/01/28

Comment: you say - let Eclipse run the "adb install" for you automatically. How?

Comment: This does not answer the question.  He wants to install the app into the system folder from Eclipse.

Comment: This does not answer the question.